# Check data before fwrite

Tags: php, file-get-contents, fwrite

I have simple script to get data from another server, run every 1 minutes.

```
<?php
$html = file_get_contents('http://google.com/data.php');


$myfile = fopen("data.html", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");

fwrite($myfile, $html);
fclose($myfile);

?>
```

But sometime, script write blank data to ***data.html***. I think because connection problem between my server and remote server, or target file just blank sometime.

I wonder if i check data after get, if received data not blank then write, if data blank then exit. Please help me how to do. Thank!

Comment: An `if` with `empty` seems like it'd work, http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php.

Comment: @chris85 don't want to be pedantic, but `"0"` also counts as empty -  perhaps it might be valid output of the `data.php` script...

Comment: @ewcz Oh, good point, code and description differ. I thought it was HTML (data.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) returns `false` on error, so you can directly check it using `===` or `!==` as

```
<?php
$html = file_get_contents('http://google.com/data.php');

if($html !== false){
    $myfile = fopen("data.html", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");

    fwrite($myfile, $html);
    fclose($myfile);
}

?>
```

if you want to merely test whether the output is empty, you can use for example the comparison `$html !== false && $html !== ''`